# How to get selected option of parsed html document

Tags: html, flutter

I'm trying to read the contents of another webpage and displaying some information in my flutter app. In this case I'm trying to read the selected option of a select element. Later I would like to change it, but that's something for another question I guess - already having trouble reading it.
When I use `.text` I just get all options, but I just want the selected one.

In the example below I would like to return "Books" - the default selected value in a select on this website: https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-select-tag.html.

If you know a better way to do it than using that http and html packages I'm using, let me know ;)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'; 
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

Future<String> initiate(BaseClient client) async {
  final url = "https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-select-tag.html";
  Response response = await client.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode != 200) return [response.body];
  var document = parse(response.body);
  //Get Html elements
  Element eSelect = document.querySelector('select');

  //TODO get selected option text
  //eSelect.text ain't cuttin' it :(
  return eSelect.text;
}
```

When I print the result I just get:

```
I/flutter (14010): 
I/flutter (14010):         Books
I/flutter (14010):         HTML
I/flutter (14010):         CSS
I/flutter (14010):         PHP
I/flutter (14010):         JavaScript
I/flutter (14010):
```